# Identifying consecutive ranges using SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Given the following table, how can I write a query, run in redshift, which outputs one row per consecutive date ranges by group?

```
GRP     EVENT_DATE
A       2023-03-19
A       2023-03-20
A       2023-03-21
A       2023-03-23
B       2023-03-25
B       2023-03-26
```

My desired output would be the following:

```
GRP    START_DATE    END_DATE   
A      2023-03-19    2023-03-21
A      2023-03-23    2023-03-23
B      2023-03-25    2023-03-26
```

Comment: Why is B from 3/25 to 3/28? Wouldn't B have 2 rows since the dates are not consecutive?

Comment: Totally right - thanks for pointing that out. Fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
WITH GROUPS AS
         (SELECT
              GRP
            , DATEADD(DAY, -ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GRP ORDER BY EVENT_DATE), EVENT_DATE)::DATE AS CAT
            , EVENT_DATE
          FROM DATES
          )
SELECT
    GRP
  , MIN(EVENT_DATE) AS START_DATE
  , MAX(EVENT_DATE) AS END_DATE
FROM GROUPS
GROUP BY
    GRP, CAT;
```

Based on this answer here: https://blog.jooq.org/how-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-series-of-events-in-sql/